# Spring Data Neo4j repository's save method returns null in place of UUId property

Tags: neo4j, uuid, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I use [GraphAware Neo4j UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) plugin. If I create entity using this:

```
Entity createdEntity = repository.save(entity);
```

then `createdEntity.uuid` property will always be `null`; but I see the `uuid` property is set in the db.

Moreover, if I will use the following to reload the entity:

```
Entity foundEntity = repository.findOne(id);
```

the property will be `null` again.

Seems like the entity is cached by Spring, because if I will restart my Spring application, I will be able to load entity along with `uuid` using `repository.findOne(id)`.

I need to know `uuid` right after creation of entity. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity properties are cached in the current session (believe you're using SDN 4.2.x?), so you need to reload on a new session. This is especially true for modifications made in event handlers where changes made in them are not reflected till a separate call is performed.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/#_design_consideration_session_caching for more info

Comment: Thank you, Luanne! Clearing of the session works for my case.